# Rewritting Vue.js code in pug and sidestepping directives

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

I just saw an example of Vue.js that has the following in the main app file:

```
<div>
    <Header v-bind:title="title" v-on:changeTitle="updateTitle($event)"></Header>
    <Ninjas v-bind:ninjas="ninjas"></Ninjas>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="ninja in ninjas">{{ ninja.name }}</li>
    </ul>
    <Footer v-bind:title="title"></Footer>
</div>
```

Now i just rewrote the above code in PUG to look like below:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    header( :title="title" , v-on:changeTitle="updateTitle($event)" )
      div( slot="lala" ) Why not a slot bro
    ninjas( :ninjas="ninjas" )  
      ul
        li( v-for="ninja in ninjas" ) {{ ninja.name }}
    footer(v-bind:title="title")
</template>
```

Everything works fine , except the text in my `header` component does't show , what am i doing wrong here ? As far as i can see i am passing the binding correctly by doing `:title="title" , v-on:changeTitle="updateTitle($event)"` , am i misplacing any of the attributes/directives ?

Comment: Did would try `"v-on:changeTitle"="updateTitle($event)"`

Comment: What was the HTML generated by this pug template?  It doesn't look like it will match the original.

Comment: @Graham not sure how to go about checking the generated HTML , any clues ?

Comment: "View Source" in any web browser

Comment: @Graham haha ok , sorry i taught theres another folder in which pug first compiles to HTML nd then renders in the browser